# ImportError: No module named rospkg

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, anaconda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, ROS Kinetic, and Anaconda. Python 3.6 is my default python.
Now I'm following ROS Tutorials, particularly this part:  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics.

So I wanna run this command:

```
$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
```

But I get this Error messages all the time,

```
rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rqt_graph/rqt_graph", line 5, in <module>
    from rqt_gui.main import Main
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 52, in <module>
    import roslib
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
    import rospkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospkg'
```

I've already installed ROS Packages with:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-rospkg
```

And I get the same problem in venv as well.
Thank you in advance for your answers. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302967/importerror:-no-module-named-rospkg/) by [dovulthesloth](https://answers.ros.org/users/37340/dovulthesloth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-09-10**:
The problem is probably due to Anaconda which requires you to modify your path. Search around on the site and you'll find many people with similar problems.

**Comment by [dovulthesloth](https://answers.ros.org/users/37340/dovulthesloth/) on 2018-09-10**:
Yeah I found some similar problems, I think I'll just unistall anaconda then. It is the simplest solution.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-09-10**:
I don't think that you have to uninstall Anaconda. You can probably just remove the line from your `.bashrc` file that adds Anaconda to your path. If you want to use Anaconda you can add it to your path manually. Keep in mind that I don't use Anaconda though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following up the comments by @jayess, you can remove the references to Anaconda from your `.bashrc` file (or any other startup files you have them in. You don't need to uninstall Anaconda. Removing the references to it in your startup files disables it, giving you the option of enabling it manually as needed.

[Adding a function](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) to your `.bashrc` file to enable Anaconda is a good way to make it easy to enable on an as-needed basis. (This works for anything else that goes in the `.bashrc` file as well, like ROS if you want to be able to switch distributions quickly.)

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2